# Which is better for micro frontend in Angular besides module federation, using IFrames or Angular elements?

Tags: angular, iframe, micro-frontend, angular-elements

We are looking to separate a feature in our existing main Angular application. We are considering using IFrames or web components using Angular elements. Module federation is currently not an option as it will take significantly more time to convert our application into a shell application.

What are the pros and cons for IFrames and using Angular elements?